# iOS App Preloaded Data Guidance

Tags: ios, database, preload

I'm working on an app with quite a few images and general information about them.  Are there any general guidelines about when it is a good idea to just bundle the data with your app and when it should just be downloaded on first run?  When you should use Core Data and when just keyed archiving is sufficient?  Or is there a better solution I haven't even considered?

I imagine that the data will be updated from time to time, but not frequently.  I'd like the app to be able to download updates.

Kind of a vague question, and I apologize for that.

Comment: Your question is too vague to answer. It's a "how long is a piece of string" question. The answer is "it depends"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether the initial data (images & information) is important and always the same.

If you wish to have it dynamically changed to whatever is updated on the server then you shouldn't bundle it within the app. On the other hand, if the initial data is trivial and you can just include it in the app.

Now if you wish to store the initial data locally in the app, given that the data is just images and theirs information, I would recommend to just use keyed archiving to keep things nice and simple.